# Playgrounds crashing with "unknown error" when using XML-parsing Swift libraries

Tags: xml, xcode, frameworks, swift-playground

I'm developing a custom framework that involves some XML parsing, using the [Kanna](https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Kanna) framework. Whenever I try to import my framework into a playground, the playground crashes with the following error:

```
Playground execution failed: expression failed to parse, unknown error
* thread #1: tid = 0x4e9448, 0x00000001074bf360 com.apple.dt.Xcode.PlaygroundStub-macosx`executePlayground, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
  * frame #0: 0x00000001074bf360 com.apple.dt.Xcode.PlaygroundStub-macosx`executePlayground
    frame #1: 0x00000001074bd22a com.apple.dt.Xcode.PlaygroundStub-macosx`-[PlaygroundViewBridgeService execute] + 90
    frame #2: 0x00007fffb4fc03ec CoreFoundation`__invoking___ + 140
    frame #3: 0x00007fffb4fc0271 CoreFoundation`-[NSInvocation invoke] + 289
    frame #4: 0x00007fffb4fd97a6 CoreFoundation`-[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 54
    frame #5: 0x00007fffc86ca95b ViewBridge`__68-[NSVB_ViewServiceImplicitAnimationDecodingProxy forwardInvocation:]_block_invoke + 47
    frame #6: 0x00007fffc86e9f4c ViewBridge`__runAnimationGroup_block_invoke + 21
...
```

The framework I'm developing works fine (it builds and unit tests run as expected), but it's a pain to not be able to use it in a playground.

I've put up a sample project with instructions on replicating the issue as well as the full stack trace on GitHub: https://github.com/noahcgreen/XMLTest. If `import Kanna` is removed from the 'XMLTest.swift' source file, the error disappears.

So far I've tried:

- using the [Fuzi](https://github.com/cezheng/Fuzi) framework instead of Kanna,
- installing with CocoaPods instead of Carthage,
- updating libxml2 on my device (using Homebrew), and
- starting over on a different (and new) device with a clean installation of XCode,

all unsuccessfully. I'm at my wit's end here. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

May be it will helps someone who wants to add **libxml2** library to the Xcode playground.

Follow these steps:

1. Create an empty workspace.
2. Add a playground into the workspace.
3. Add an empty framework to the workspace AND add `"$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2"` to the `'SWIFT_INCLUDE_PATHS'` in the `'Build Settings'`.
4. Add `'import libxml2'` on the playground page.

Answer (score 1):

Ok for you custom framework, first you need to make you playground a workspace

1. Open the playground and choose File > Save As Workspace
2. Open the workspace for your playground
3. In workspace Choose file -> add and then add you custom frame work.

   4. Import frame work

Notes from apple

Important: The following conditions are required for the custom framework to work in a playground:

The framework is in the same workspace as the playground.

The framework has already been built.

If it is an iOS framework, it is built for a 64-bit runtime destination.

The workspace contains at least one active scheme that builds a target.

If it is an Objective-C framework, it was built with the Defines Module (DEFINES_MODULE) build setting set to Yes.

http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.2/#/devc9b33111c Where I got my info. Hope this helps.

Edit:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <Kanna/Kanna.h>


//! Project version number for XMLTest.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT double XMLTestVersionNumber;

//! Project version string for XMLTest.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char XMLTestVersionString[];

// In this header, you should import all the public headers of your framework using statements like #import <XMLTest/PublicHeader.h>
```

ok dude try this in xmltest.h

Comment: Have you looked at the sample project that I linked? I can import my framework into my playground just fine, but once the XML framework is imported the whole thing crashes.

Comment: now I am getting this error missing required module 'libxml2'